# How to merge several data frames in R into single lesser one (reduced number of columns)?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 7 equally sized data frames with 150 columns each. If I combine them into a single data frame it amounts to a size of 3+ gb, and my csv editor just won't open it up, and the size just makes it difficult to work with in general. I wanted to pick certain variables and reduce the columns number from 150 to about 20. Can I trim the columns in just one of the 7 data frames and bind the remaining 6 to it, so that the final product would be a united data frame of only 20 variables (columns)?

P.S. I consider myself a beginner in R, could you please bear that mind when explaining, so that won't be too advanced for me? :D

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/11/5-ways-to-subset-a-data-frame-in-r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `rbind` the columns that you want.  E.g.:

```
cars1 <- mtcars
cars2 <- cars1
cols <- c(2, 5, 10)
rbind(cars1[, cols], cars2[, cols])
                     cyl drat gear
Mazda RX4              6 3.90    4
Mazda RX4 Wag          6 3.90    4
Datsun 710             4 3.85    4
Hornet 4 Drive         6 3.08    3
Hornet Sportabout      8 3.15    3
Valiant                6 2.76    3
Duster 360             8 3.21    3
```

Comment: Great.  Please up-vote the answer to complete.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried but it immediately cancels itself and show this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I will upvote it once I have 15 reputation tho :D